# mailto: is not working on UncontrolledTooltip

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, email

I tried to make a clickable external mail link in the hover section.
When the user hovers the mouse on the **some text**, tooltip appears and user clicks the **some@example.com**, but the mail app is not showing.

Same code works outside of it, I am not sure why.

```
import {
  Badge,
  UncontrolledTooltip,
} from "reactstrap"

<Badge
                pill
                className="badge-soft-success me-1 text-uppercase font-size-12"
                id="superTip"
              >
                Some Text&nbsp;<i className="mdi mdi-alert-circle-outline"></i>
              </Badge>
              <UncontrolledTooltip placement="right-start" target="superTip" delay={{hide : 2000}}>
                Congratulations 
                <a href="mailto:some@example.com" className="text-signin ps-2">
                  some@example.com
                </a>
              </UncontrolledTooltip>
```

Answer (score 0):

Having links inside of a tooltip won't work, because the tooltip disappears once you stop hovering over the original text. You probably want a [popover](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/popovers/) instead, which won't go away as easily.

Comment: I thought popover, but can't use it because this code is used in other parts and it has click event, I set the time for 2s not disappearing automatically. Still not sure what I can do as a solution

Answer (score 0):

I solved as follows

```
<UncontrolledTooltip placement="right-start" target="superTip" delay={{hide : 2000}} onClick={e=>e.stopPropagation()}>
                Congratulations 
                <a href="mailto:some@example.com" className="text-signin ps-2">
                  some@example.com
                </a>
              </UncontrolledTooltip>
```